# Apache cannot read certificate file

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, openssl

I use self-signed certificates with no issue but today I have tried to create a SSL certificate for commercial use. But apache doesn't start and gives the following error:

Notice: I have confirmed that crt file is valid as [CSR decoder](http://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html) loads the content as well.

*AH02241: Init: Unable to read server certificate from file XXXX/XXXX/XXXX.csr
SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=X509)
AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.*

**Softwares**: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013 , Apache HTTP 2.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using CSR instead of the certificate file. Make sure you have created self-signed certificate with 
`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt`
and use the server.crt in the SSLCertificateFile setting in apache ssl config.
If you are using a commercial signing authority you must use the certificate provided by the authority and not the signing request generated.

Comment: yes, I have checked. Starts with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- , and ends with -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: checked that the apache user has permissions to access the csr files and key files?

Comment: yes, it has....

Comment: ok and anything in ssl_error_log?

Comment: Nope, everything is just fine. "openssl req -text -noout -verify -in XXX.csr" AND
"openssl rsa -in XXX.key -check"

Comment: openssl x509 -in XXX.crt -text works as well?

Comment: As I wrote above, it is not Self-Signed Certificate but Certificate signing request (CSR)

Comment: wait a sec. you are trying to boot apache with a CSR? it is incorrect it needs a certificate not a CSR.

Comment: I am new to certificates, until today I didn't install any certificates for commercial use. So, can you be a litte clear ?

Comment: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3&nav=0,33 I used to create that cert.

Comment: I see missing a crucial step of generating a self signed certificate
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey myserver.key -out server.crt
server.crt you then add to the SSLCertificateFile option in Apache config

Comment: SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    "XXX.csr"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "XXX.key"
  SSLCACertificateFile  "ca-certificates.crt"

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your interest but as I repeated few times, I don't create Self - Signed Certificate, you only give me ss cert examples.

Comment: Apache will not boot without certificate. CSR is a request for certificate you send to signing authorities to get the certificate back that will be used to start Apache.

Comment: I ran the command but this time the page displays: "This Connection is Untrusted" , but my cert is comodo

Comment: yes, this is how self-signed certificate works. You need a root authority to sign CSR to create a legit/trusted certificate. Examples of root authorities are VeriSign, GoDaddy etc. Pretty much any provider of SSL Certification services.

Comment: apologies I didnt understand did Comodo provide you with a CRT file?

Comment: OK, finally I understand what you're talking about. I now understand how commercial SSLs work. And yes, It works now. I have created the certificate that given by Comodo and restarted Apache. So, if you edit your answer as you tell CSR and CRT are different by pointing this comments, So I can accept your answer.